# How to test the redux form in jest

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, redux-form

I am using a stateless component which has reduxform in it.I am trying to write unit test for the login form to get the input details as well as to simulate the form on click. but i don't know where to start since i am new to jest.

I have tried to create snapshot as well as creating a mock store.

Login Form Component:

```
import logo from 'assets/img/logo/logo_200.png';
import LoadingButton from 'components/LoadingButton';
import ReduxFormInput from 'components/ReduxFormInput';
import { password } from 'lib/normalize';
import React from 'react';
import { Form } from 'reactstrap';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import validate from './validate';

const SignInForm = (props: any) => {
  const { handleSubmit, isLoading } = props;
  return (
    <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div className="text-center pb-4">
        <img src={logo} className="rounded" style={{ width: 60, height: 60 }} alt="logo" />
      </div>
      <Field
        name="email"
        component={ReduxFormInput}
        placeHolder="your@email.com"
        label="Email"
        type="email"
      />
      <Field
        name="password"
        component={ReduxFormInput}
        placeHolder="your password"
        label="Password"
        type="password"
        normalize={password}
      />
      <hr />
      <LoadingButton
        text="Login"
        loadingText="Logging in"
        isLoading={isLoading}
        size="lg"
        block={true}
      />
    </Form>
  );
};

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'signIn',
  validate,
})(SignInForm);
```

Redux Form Input Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { FormGroup, Input, Label } from 'reactstrap';
import 'styles/splash-scripts.css';

const ReduxFormInput: React.FC = (field: any) => (
  <FormGroup>
    <Label>{field.label}</Label>
    <Input {...field.input} type={field.type} placeholder={field.placeHolder} />
    {field.meta.touched && <p className="text-danger">{field.meta.error}</p>}
  </FormGroup>
);

export default ReduxFormInput;
```

Test File:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow, mount, render } from 'enzyme';
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import configureMockStore from "redux-mock-store";

import SignInForm from '../../src/pages/Public/SignIn/SignInForm';

const mockStore = configureMockStore();
const store = mockStore({});


const defaultProps = {
  submitting: false,
  handleSubmit: () => {},
  invalid: false,
  initialValues: {},
};
describe("Login Component", () => {

  it('should match the snapshot', () => {
      const wrapper = renderer.create(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <SignInForm />
        </Provider>
    ).toJSON();
      expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

  it('it renders a <form /> element', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(
      <Provider store={store}>
         <SignInForm {...defaultProps} />
      </Provider>
    ).dive();
  });
});
```

I have tried to use

```
    const emailState = wrapper.state().email;
    const passwordState = wrapper.state().password;
    expect(emailState).toEqual('');
    expect(passwordState).toEqual('');
```

but i got an error

```
error: reactwrapper::state() can only be called on class components
```

Comment: do you attempt to set an email in your state somewhere in your test? Normally you would initialise the store with any state you need and then check the rendering of your components from that. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @WillJenkins No i am not storing the email or password in state since i am using redux form it will get stored in the store. I am trying to check whether the input is of type email and to give an email address and password and try to simulate the button on click

Answer (score 2):

As the error says, you can't call `state()` on a `reactWrapper`. From your comment, it seems that you're trying to check the type and contents of the empty email and password fields. If that's the case, you can `find` by name like this:

```
const emailField = wrapper.find('[name="email"]')
const passwordField = wrapper.find('[name="password"')
```

You can then check the values and types as needed.

Comment: i have tried the above but i am getting error like this

  expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: ""
    Received: {}

Comment: `emailField` and `passWordField` are the components. To check e.g. the value you can use `emailField.instance().value`

Comment: Added the instance().value but getting error like Property 'value' does not exist on type 'Component<{}, {}, any>'. Removed value and checked but then the error was like ShallowWrapper::instance() can only be called on the root

Comment: try inspecting `emailField.debug()` to check what's being rendered

Comment: it is empty no data